# how to compare two arrays

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've an array - `$scope.question = [];` which store data which get from web api: id, question and correctAnswer

```
        quizService.getQuestions(id).success(function (data) {
            $scope.question = data;
        });
```

And, I've another array, which store answered question by user:

```
    $scope.binding = {
        answers: {}
    };

    $scope.setAnswer = function (answer, id) {
        $scope.binding.answers[id] = answer;
    };
```

The question is, how to get data from array and compare them?

```
    $scope.question[id]
    $scope.question[correctAnswer]
```

Will be this correct realization?

```
   if ($scope.binding.answers[id] == $scope.question[id] && $scope.binding.answer[answer] == $scope.question[correctAnswer]) {
          ...
    }
```

P.S. I'm newbie in angularjs.

**update 1: some more data**
    function controller($scope, quizService) {

```
    $scope.currentAnswer = null;
    //Set the answer from radio buttons
    $scope.setAnswer = function (answer, id) {
        $scope.binding.answers[id] = answer;
    };
    $scope.question = [];
    $scope.binding = {
        answers: {}
    };

    updQuestion();

    function updQuestion() {
        var id = 1;

       //Get the question
        quizService.getQuestions(id).success(function (data) {
            $scope.question = data;
        });

        //Button to get next question
        $scope.nextQuestion = function () {
            id++;
            quizService.getQuestions(id).success(function (data) {
                $scope.question = data;
                $scope.currentAnswer = $scope.binding.answers[id];
            });
        };

     //Submit button when user passed all questions
     $scope.onSubmit = function () {

            quizService.postResult().sucess(function () {

                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.question.length; i++) {

                    if ($scope.binding.answers[id] == $scope.question[id] && $scope.binding.answer[answer] == $scope.question[correctAnswer]) {
                        numbOfCorrectAnswers++;
                    }
                    $scope.question.push(numbOfCorrectAnswers);
                }
            });
        };
```

**Update 2**

So, I've tryed with 2 for loop and forEach, anyway can't get values from the objects in arrays.

```
 $scope.onSubmit = function () {
                var numbOfCorrectAnswers = 0;
                var answers = null;
                var n = 0;
                var b = 0;
                var questions;
                for (n = 0; n < $scope.getQuestions.lenght; n++) {
                    for (b = 0; b < $scope.binding.answers.lenght; b++) {
                    var questions = $scope.getQuestions[n];
                    var getAnswer = $scope.binding.answer[n];
                    if (questions.Id == getAnswer.id && questions.CorrectAnswer == getAnswer.answer) {
                        numbOfCorrectAnswers++;
                    }

                });
```

Comment: In my opinion, we need more details to solve this question. Can you share more code indicate where is each part that you attach? 
And show the format of the data.
That could help the people to help you.

Comment: @Neil Ofcouse, already update it

Comment: Sorry, I really don't understand your code and what do you are trying to do. Do you want to compare two arrays?

Comment: Yes, the data which store in the arrays, if it of course possible

Comment: the title of this question is misleading.  your problem isn't with binding or APIs, it's with how to compare two arrays.

Comment: @Claies oh yeah, sorry, I just didn't know how to work with objects, which receive data from the api.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare both arrays like this:

`$scope.name.Xarray[i] == $scope.name.Yarray[n]`, where `i` is a number in array the position.

Then you have to know that you have the iterate both arrays. You can use `for` or `while` loop. Example:

```
  for ( n in $scope.Xarray.lenght ) {
    for ( i in $scope.Yarray.lenght ) {
      Xarray[n] == Yarray[i]
    }
  }
```

It's only an example and doesn't mean that is exactly like this, but you go ahead with these info.

Comment: I've tryed to do this, it's not helped me. I've update this topic